# Low latency and plughw:* vs hw:* devices

Tags: linux, alsa

I'm having fun tinkering around ALSA and I would like to achieve a very low latency stream from capture to playback device (btw, I cannot find some example code to read about this, do you know any? I find a lot of only-capture / only-playback code).

My question is if, latency wise, I should use the `hw:*` devices and handle by myself the limitations they have or the convience provided by the `plughw:*` devices is enough good that I should prefer the latter.

For example: I want move the audio stream inside my application in float32 sample format, and the `plughw:*` device takes care of the convertion of float32 to/from the format required by the audio card hardware. If use the `hw:*` device and I do by myself this convertion (among other things I'm now required to handle) can I achieve a better latency? Or I shouldn't bother?

Thanks in advance for your wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

The conversions in the `plug` plugin are done on each sample on the fly, so there is no additional latency.
You would get latency only when there is additional buffering, such as in the `dmix` plugin.